# Sequelize, Many-To-Many On Non-ID Properties

Tags: many-to-many, sequelize.js

I have one model, `Target`, which has a property/field called `targetName`. I have a second model, `Operation`, with a field `verb`. Both these models have a `primaryKey` field named `id`.

I have a third model, `Policy`, that is a defined association/join with additional properties; `Policy` also contains `targetName` and `verb` fields. How do I specify in the `belongsToMany()` for `Target` and `Operation` to use the fields above, instead of defaulting to the id field? I know of the `through` option to specify the actual model. What's in the ellipsis section below?

`Target.belongsToMany(Operation, {through: Policy, ...});`
and
`Operation.belongsToMany(Target, {through: Policy, ...});`

Also, do I just specify the two `belongsToMany()`?

Comment: What is the meaning of `How do I specify in the belongsToMany() for Target and Operation to use the fields above, instead of defaulting to the id field?` ? It seems here that `Policy` is your join table. And hence shouldn't it just stores foreignKeys of ids of `Target` and `Operation` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do foreign keys pointing to non-primary keys in sequelize. See https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2967